# Can't scrape a table with rvest

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I've been trying to scrape a table from this page: https://ficeda.com.mx/index.php?id=precios

My code looks like this

```
url_data <- "https://ficeda.com.mx/index.php?id=precios"

url_data %>% 
  read_html() %>% 
  html_node(xpath = "/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[3]/table[1]") %>% 
  html_table()
```

But it gives me this error: Error in UseMethod("html_table") :
no applicable method for 'html_table' applied to an object of class "xml_missing"

Does anyone know what might be going on?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That data is actually inside an iframe. Either, make your initial request and extract the src link from the iframe, and then make a request there, or, simply make a request direct to the iframe document:

```
library(rvest)

url_data <- "https://www.ficeda.com.mx/app_precios/pages/index/v2"

url_data %>% 
  read_html() %>% 
  html_node('.category_title + table') %>% 
  html_table()
```

---

The iframe src from original endpoint:

```
read_html('https://ficeda.com.mx/index.php?id=precios') %>% html_node('#linea2') %>% html_attr('src')
```